# warning C4805 when compiling bitwise OR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to convert some boolean flags to the single integer value in the following way:

```
bool flag1, flag2;
...
int  res = flag1 | (flag2 << 1);
```

I've got the warning (VC++2015):

```
warning C4805: '|': unsafe mix of type 'bool' and type 'int' in operation
```

However it is compiled successfully if I explicitly convert bool to int:

```
int  res = int(flag1) | (isCacheable << 1);
```

The MSDN says that "*This warning is generated for **comparison** operations between bool and int.*"

Why does the compiler generate the warning C4805 when compiling bitwise OR?

Comment: hmm. not sure.  It could be there to stop people from accidentally using bitwise or when they meant to use logical or.

Comment: Taking a bool and shifting it and then bitwise or-ing it with a bool looks strange to me. I'd ask if this is really what you want. Seems like the compiler agrees with me.

Comment: The compiler writer thinks you're not smart enough to understand the code that you wrote. It's up to you to decide whether you believe it.

Comment: @WernerHenze -- both `bool`s get promoted to `int` in that expression: `false` becomes 0 and `true` becomes 1.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know that. I understand what the code does. But when I see such code I would take a second look if the code author also understands that and if the code is correct. I don't say that this code is wrong. But it is unusual enough to double check it.

Comment: The cast is highly sensible, move on with your life.

Comment: This seems to be a specific case of compilers issuing warnings for implicit casts that often appear by accident. I recommend explicitly casting to int, not only to silence an unneeded warning, but also to make it instantly clear to someone reading the code (including you in the future) what it does and that it was intentional on your part.

Comment: The warning seems misleading in this case, because it's not the same as the MSDN example (bool==int) .  I'm wondering if it may be something like "supposing of misusing of the operator '|'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this a warning, because when people try to do bit-wise on booleans they actually mean logical comparison. There should be no reason whatsoever to do bit-wise operations on boolean values.

Comment: OP does not do bitwise operations on bool. The bitwise OR is done between two ints and stored in an int.

Comment: @patatahooligan `bool flag1, flag2; int  res = flag1 | (flag2 << 1);` ?

Comment: Neither of those operators works on boolean types so that's basically `int res = int(flag1) | (int(flag2) << 1);` Yes there are two `bool`s, but there is no bitwise operation on `bool`.

Comment: @patatahooligan that is moot point. That would be akin to saying 'bitwise operations are not performed on shorts'.

Comment: Each `bool` sets a different bit of `res`. How can you claim that doing bit-wise operations on boolean types has no meaning if your understand that?

Comment: Like i said, bitwise operation on boolean makes no sense, and this is exactly what compiler warns about. In those examples, flags are not `booleans`, and should have been `unsigned int` from the very beginning.